# Why does zlib have an enforced maximum wbits?

Tags: compression, zlib

Why bound the size of the history buffer for compression? 2^15 bits is quite small if you have repeated text spread across a large file.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2<sup>15</sup> *bytes*, not bits.

zlib is based on the deflate format, developed in 1993 when machines had much less memory than today.

If you would like to compress with farther lookback, then try [LZMA2](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html), which can go up to a 2<sup>32</sup>-1 byte dictionary size, at the cost of memory usage and compression time.